# Set initial size for NSWindow

Tags: macos, cocoa, size, nswindow

I'm trying to set an initial size for my NSWindow. First, I tried to set size using storyboard.

[image]

And then I tried the code below, the both don't work.

```
NSWindow *mainWindow = [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0];
mainWindow.titleVisibility=NSWindowTitleHidden;
NSRect frame = mainWindow.frame;
frame.size=CGSizeMake(1000, 200);
[mainWindow setFrame:frame display:YES];
```

I tried to check or uncheck the "Restorable" attribute. How can I set an initial size for NSWindow? Why are these not working?

Comment: Where are you doing this? It should work if you subclass NSWindow and write your code in awakeFromNib.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to set the initial window size in the storyboard editor of Xcode.
Instead of setting the size of the window, you need to set it on the ViewControllers first element like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for including the image directly. I would have done it myself but new users are not allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a storyboard with macOS 10.15.5 or newer, the initial size of the `NSWindow` may be result of the sum of all containing `NSView` objects in the `contentViewController`. This may result in a larger window than in earlier macOS versions.

To fix unexpected large window sizes, search for large `NSView` objects in your storyboard, and make them smaller. Keep resizing and testing until the initial window size is to your liking.